# Rocket Combustion

Tags: temperature, combustion, pressure, thermodynamics

How is the chamber pressure is arrived at for a given combustion temperature and mixture ratio ?
Based on the mixture ratio, the value of gamma and temperature can be found out, using chemical kinetics, but what about the equilibrium pressure ? Is it sufficient to use rocket equation to arrive at pressure for a given thrust or does thermodynamic equilibrium (**Chemical kinetics**) plays a role in deciding it  ??
Also, Is pressure decided based on **autoignition temperature** since, pressure is inversely proportional to autoignition temperature ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the chamber pressure has a lot to do with the nozzle cross section. So you should be looking at the gas equation.

Comment: This is an extremely complicated bit of engineering and certainly depends on the propellants in use as well as the designed max fire time, peak thrust desired, and so on.

Comment: I'm no expert, but considering the flow goes the speed of sound at the nozzle throat, I think we can throw equilibrium and quasi-equilibrium out the window. And the combustion isn't necessarily even completed by the time you get to the nozzle throat. Like Carl said, it's a complicated problem. Sorry to be not very helpful.